# Windows 7 DNS stuck at manual

Tags: windows-7, dns

I am using the google dns servers most of the time, but for one particular wifi connection it blocks that ip so I have to revert back to automatically choosing DNS...

The problem now is everytime I connect to this network, I have to change it back to automatic DNS manually (ironically), it's stuck on using the google DNS by default...

It's a trivial problem, but would be fab if someone can help me out here...

Comment: Just provide a third DNS IP Address.  Just figure out what address it would use if you allowed the access point to assign your DNS Server and use that and/or use OpenDNS

Comment: The problem is the Wifi network i'm connecting to seems to be blocking most if not all external DNS. So I need to have it set to automatic, otherwise I cannot connect to the internet. But the damn setting refuses to stick with automatic and I have to end up setting it to automatic everytime I connect to this Wifi network...

Comment: somehow it solved itself without me knowing how <_<